# How to wait for threads to finish without blocking GUI?

Tags: c#, multithreading, data-partitioning

I have array of 2863 objects. I want in two "runs" per 1000 objects read array data by 4 threads (running PC # of CPUs).

Currenly my source code is partitioning data to correct number of threads and runs:

> Single run size (default) = 1000 elements
> Number of runs = 2
> Extra thread run size = 866 elements
>
> Starting run [1 / 2]
> Thread as readDCMTags(i=0,firstIndex=0, lastIndex=249
> Thread as readDCMTags(i=1,firstIndex=250, lastIndex=499
> Thread as readDCMTags(i=2,firstIndex=500, lastIndex=749
> Thread as readDCMTags(i=3,firstIndex=750, lastIndex=999
>
> Starting run [2 / 2]
> Thread as readDCMTags(i=0,firstIndex=1000, lastIndex=1249
> Thread as readDCMTags(i=1,firstIndex=1250, lastIndex=1499
> Thread as readDCMTags(i=2,firstIndex=1500, lastIndex=1749
> Thread as readDCMTags(i=3,firstIndex=1750, lastIndex=1999
> Extra Thread as readDCMTags(i=1,firstIndex=2000, lastIndex=2865

However current source code is starting all threads at once, it is not waiting for RUN TO END. When I join threads from current run, the GUI is hanging out. How to solve the issue?

Source Code is:

```
nrOfChunks = 2866 / 1000;
int leftOverChunk = 2866  % 1000;

for(int z = 0; z < nrOfChunks; z++)
{
    addToStatusPanel("\nStarting run [" + (z+1).ToString() + " / " + nrOfChunks.ToString() + "]");

    int indexesPerThread = 1000 / 5; #nrOfThreads
    int leftOverIndexes = 1000 % 5; #nrOfThreads

    threads = new Thread[nrOfThreads];
    threadProgress = new int[nrOfThreads];
    threadDCMRead = new int[nrOfThreads];

    for(int i = 0; i < nrOfThreads; i++)
    {
        int firstIndex = (i * indexesPerThread+z*Convert.ToInt32(chunkSizeTextBox.Text));
        int lastIndex = firstIndex + indexesPerThread - 1;

        if(i == (nrOfThreads- 1))
        {
            if(i == (nrOfThreads - 1))
            {
                lastIndex += leftOverIndexes;
            }
        }

        addToStatusPanel("readDCMTags(i=" + i.ToString() + ",firstIndex=" + firstIndex.ToString() + ", lastIndex=" + lastIndex.ToString());

        threads[i] = new Thread(() => readDCMTags(i.ToString(), firstIndex, lastIndex));
        threads[i].Name = i.ToString();

       threads[i].Start();
    }

    if(z == (nrOfChunks - 1))
    {
        int firstIndex = (nrOfChunks * Convert.ToInt32(chunkSizeTextBox.Text));
        int lastIndex = firstIndex + leftOverChunk - 1;

        addToStatusPanel("readDCMTags(i=" + z.ToString() + ",firstIndex=" + firstIndex.ToString() + ", lastIndex=" + lastIndex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Adding after  a loop `for(int i = 0; i < nrOfThreads; i++)` a join command for the threads array, before going for next next run loop `for(int z = 0; z < nrOfChunks; z++)` is hanging the GUI.

Comment: Don't wait in event handlers for threads to finish, (or anything else).  Stop using Join(). Invoke/BeginInvoke.

Comment: Put another way, if you call a blocking wait inside a state-machine action routine, it will stop processing inputs.

Comment: Put all your code above in a BackgroundWorker and listen to the RunWorkerCompleted event. (but use TPL or PLINQ instead of threads. It is a a lot easier)

Answer (score 3):

By definition, if you wait, you block (the current executing threads blocks waiting for something else).

What you want, instead, is for something to happen when all threads are finished. That, "all threads have finished" is an event. So your best option will be to wait in a background thread and fire the event when all threads complete.

If the GUI is interested on that, then the GUI thread will need to subscribe to that particular event.

**Edit:** Pseudocode (not tested, just the idea).

```
waitBg = new Thread(() => 
  {
    foreach (thread in threads)
      thread.WaitFor();

     // All threads have finished
     if (allThreadFinishedEvent != null)
        allThreadFinishedEvent();
  }
);
```

Then, on the handler for the allThreadFinishedEvent you do whatever you want to do (remember to dispatch it to the main thread if you want to change something in the UI, as that'll be executed in the bg thread context).

Comment: Ok, so I should set each thread as background in inner loop and then how to stop main loop? How to hold main loop with until event will occur?

Answer (score 0):

How about placing this threading logic in a backgroundworker and sending back the result of your backgroundworker to your interface. This way, your interface will not be locked while the program is processing the threads.

you can find the msdn example of initializing and using the [backgroundworker here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

I think that should be the correct way forward.

Comment: I will have to create an array of background workers, which method or command will hold the main loop from continuing?

Comment: Not quite sure if I understand what you mean but basically, how I solved problems of "hanging" GUI's in the past is by using the main method for interface and all the events it does are just being handled by your main thread. Your main thread (or an event, depending on your needs) will start your backgroundworker via backgroundworker_DoWork and you can capture the "progress" via WorkerSupportsProgress. Inside this backgroundworker, that will operate on a different thread than your main, you can put your code. Your GUI uses a different thread and will not be affected and it can show progress